# No analog sound in Raspberry Pi 3

Tags: pi-3, audio

I have a Raspberry Pi 3 with Raspbian Buster installed. When playing Youtube I get no sound through speakers connected by audio jack. After some research, I did the following:

1.Audio output is set to Analog

2.By executing `aplay -L` in terminal I get the following audio options:

```
null
 Discard all samples (playback) or generate zero samples (capture)
jack
 JACK Audio Connection Kit
pulse
 PulseAudio Sound Server
default
 Playback/recording through the PulseAudio sound server output
sysdefault:CARD=b1
 bcm2835 HDMI 1, bcm2835 HDMI 1
 Default Audio Device
dmix:CARD=b1,DEV=0
 bcm2835 HDMI 1, bcm2835 HDMI 1
 Direct sample mixing device
dsnoop:CARD=b1,DEV=0
 bcm2835 HDMI 1, bcm2835 HDMI 1
 Direct sample snooping device
hw:CARD=b1,DEV=0
 bcm2835 HDMI 1, bcm2835 HDMI 1
 Direct hardware device without any conversions
plughw:CARD=b1,DEV=0
 bcm2835 HDMI 1, bcm2835 HDMI 1
 Hardware device with all software conversions
usbstream:CARD=b1
 bcm2835 HDMI 1
 USB Stream Output
sysdefault:CARD=Headphones
 bcm2835 Headphones, bcm2835 Headphones
 Default Audio Device
dmix:CARD=Headphones,DEV=0
 bcm2835 Headphones, bcm2835 Headphones
 Direct sample mixing device
dsnoop:CARD=Headphones,DEV=0
 bcm2835 Headphones, bcm2835 Headphones
 Direct sample snooping device
hw:CARD=Headphones,DEV=0
 bcm2835 Headphones, bcm2835 Headphones
 Direct hardware device without any conversions
plughw:CARD=Headphones,DEV=0
 bcm2835 Headphones, bcm2835 Headphones
 Hardware device with all software conversions
usbstream:CARD=Headphones
 bcm2835 Headphones
 USB Stream Output
```

3.I managed to get sound (a voice saying "Front left, front right") by executing in terminal any of the following commands:

```
speaker-test -c2 -twav -l7 -D sysdefault:1
speaker-test -c2 -twav -l7 -D plughw:1,0
speaker-test -c2 -twav -l7 -D hw:1,0
```

Any ideas how this can be fixed?

Comment: I managed to fix this by following this guide https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/112954/how-to-restore-audio-output-after-updating-raspbian-buster-on-pi4

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to restore audio output after updating Raspbian Buster on Pi4](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/112954/how-to-restore-audio-output-after-updating-raspbian-buster-on-pi4)